# Possible to combine method-shorthand with fat-arrows in ES2015?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know ES2015 has method shorthand:

```js
let obj = {
  myMethod() {
    alert("STUFF!");
  }
};
```

I also know it has fat arrow support:

```js
let myMethod = () => alert("STUFF!");
```

**But is it possible to combine the two**? This does not seem to work:

```js
let obj = {
  myMethod() => alert("STUFF!")
};
```

The closest I could get is this, but it doesn't use the method-shorthand:

```js
let obj = {
  myMethod: () => alert("STUFF!")
};
```

If not currently supported, is this something planned for future revisions?

Comment: Only one question: **Why?**

Comment: Trying to understand the capabilities/limits of the language

Comment: Those two do very different things. What would you like/expect their combination to do?

Comment: The individual use cases make sense to me and I was surprised to find that they do not work together.

Comment: What would you expect `alert(this)` to do if it was found in your "arrow method"?

Comment: @Bergi: I expected `myMethod() => alert(this)` to be equivalent to `myMethod: () => alert(this)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But is it possible to combine the two?

No.

> If not currently supported, is this something planned for future revisions?

No, it is too insignificant. As you can see in your example, it can be achieved with just a single colon, and nothing else would be different.

> The individual use cases make sense to me and I was surprised to find that they do not work together.

You have to consider method definitions as a fourth form of a function definition (function declaration, function expression, arrow functions, methods). As such, it doesn't make sense to "combine" them.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: I would distinguish (standard) functions, generator functions, classes, arrow functions, methods and generator methods; but well…